# Old SSTables not removed after running major compaction on TWCS table

Tags: cassandra

I am in a new system where two different TTLs (30 days and 90 days) are being used with TWCS compaction. As a result, the team needs to do major compaction (STCS) every 40-50 days, which is affecting performance.

Last week major compaction was initiated which was completed yesterday and I have seen they never used split-output (-s) option. There is already  2 huge sstable (10 gb compacted and 300 gb uncompacted as an output of this compaction.

1. Post STCS compaction, along with 2 bigger SSTables ,older sstables still coexist (since mid Dec 2022). What may be the reason?
2. If next time the team will run compaction with split option, will that bigger file be split? Or do we have to use sstablesplit to get that splitted?
3. In 2 out of 5 nodes some sstables are there since July 2022 in the data file path. What may be the problem ?? I have observed some sstable files in snapshot directory...is this the issue??

Comment: Does the application *only* perform inserts into this TWCS table and that there is no further updates or deletes to the data?

Comment: Yes...TTL takes care of the delete

Answer (score 2):

Performing a major compaction on TWCS tables does not make sense because of how the strategy works.

With the `TimeWindowCompactionStrategy` (or TWCS), SSTables which belong within the same time window are compacted together into a single SSTable using `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy` (or STCS). After the STCS compaction completes, there is no further compaction done in TWCS.

A major compaction with the "split" option makes no sense since it splits the data into files which are 50%, 25%, 12.5%, etc of the total size. This is completely against the goal of TWCS which is to merge all the data into a single SSTable for every time window.

If a TTL is set on the data and `gc_grace_seconds` has passed, SSTables which have 100% fully expired data are dropped (deleted from the filesystem) without compaction -- it happens automatically without manual intervention.

If the table contains data with different TTLs, it indicates that perhaps you don't have a true timeseries use case so TWCS is not a good fit. If so, we recommend you switch to STCS. Otherwise, let TWCS do its job.

If you haven't already seen it, I recommend having a look at the resources below to get a better understanding on how Cassandra compactions work. Cheers!

- Doc - [How data is maintained in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataMaintain.html)
- Video - [DataStax Academy DS201 - Compaction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69sHSF0iUqg&list=PL2g2h-wyI4Spf5rzSmesewHpXYVnyQ2TS&index=19)
- Video - [DataStax Academy DS210 - Time Window Compaction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8jPlppa_8I&list=PL2g2h-wyI4SrHMlHBJVe_or_Ryek2THgQ&index=17)

Comment: Hello Erick.Yes,as each sstable contains both 30 and 90 days TTL so an sstable is supposed to be dropped only after the time>90 days but here team  faced node down issue after around 60-70 days and they taken the strategy to do manual compaction.I am thinking of proposing to create different tables for different TTL so that TWCS can effectively remove SStable automatically per time. But as we have a big sstable of >250 gb which definitely accumulated lot of tombstones so what would be the immediate resolution...should we go for sstable split or next compaction with -s option. Plz suggest

Comment: Point number 1 is resolved after node restart.